# How to copy embeded object and paste in temp folder with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have to create a code to save configuration script of routers from specified list.

1. Using telnet and VBA I'm able to fulfill my requirement. But telnet window is visible every time and also I have to rely on SendKeys to send Commands properly to that telnet window.
2. I have embedded  'plink.exe' as an "Object 7" in Sheet1. below is the code which copies this object and paste created of today's date in temp folder:

   ```
   EmbeddedObject.Copy
   Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(sFolder & Chr(0))
   oFolder.Self.InvokeVerb "Paste"
   ```
3. Here the problem is after copy-paste, the file is showing as corrupted. I tried adding a zip file, but zip also gets corrupted.
4. So I had added a code to open the object within Excel and using SendKeys and 7z Extractor I extract to temp folder again relying on SendKeys.

Please help me with to copy it in better way without getting file corrupted.

Here is my code.

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
    Private Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
#End If

Private Type FUNC_OUT_RESULTS
    SUCCESS As Boolean
    SAVED_FILE_PATH_NAME As String
    ERROR As String
End Type


Sub test()
    Dim tRes As FUNC_OUT_RESULTS
    Dim oleObj As OLEObject

    tRes = SaveEmbeddedOleObjectToDisk _
    (EmbeddedObject:=ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("Object 7"), FilePathName:="C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\20170512\")

    With tRes
        If .SUCCESS Then
            MsgBox "OleObject successfully saved as : '" & .SAVED_FILE_PATH_NAME & " '", vbInformation
        Else
            MsgBox .ERROR, vbCritical
        End If
    End With
End Sub


Private Function SaveEmbeddedOleObjectToDisk( _
    ByVal EmbeddedObject As OLEObject, _
    ByVal FilePathName As String _
    ) _
    As FUNC_OUT_RESULTS


    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim sFolder As String

    On Error GoTo errHandler
    If Len(Dir$(FilePathName)) <> 0 Then 'Err.Raise 58
        Dim FSO As Object
        Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

        FSO.deletefile FilePathName & "\*.*", True    'Delete files
        FSO.deletefolder FilePathName                'Delete Todays Date folder
        MkDir FilePathName                          'Make Todays Date folder
    End If
'\---------------------------------------\
    sFolder = Left$(FilePathName, InStrRev(FilePathName, "\") - 10)
    If Len(Dir$(sFolder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir sFolder
    End If
    If EmbeddedObject.OLEType = xlOLEEmbed Then
        EmbeddedObject.Verb Verb:=xlPrimary   '\---Here it opens within excel

        Set EmbeddedObject = Nothing
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        Dim oShell
        Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
        oShell.AppActivate sFolder & "\plink*"
        oShell.SendKeys "{F5}"         '\----it extracts to temp-----------\
        oShell.SendKeys FilePathName
        oShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        oShell.AppActivate sFolder & "\plink*"
        oShell.SendKeys ("%{F4}")

'----Copy the object without opening-----

' EmbeddedObject.Copy
' Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(sFolder & Chr(0))
' oFolder.Self.InvokeVerb "Paste"
'\---------------------------------------\

        SaveEmbeddedOleObjectToDisk.SAVED_FILE_PATH_NAME = FilePathName
        SaveEmbeddedOleObjectToDisk.SUCCESS = True
    End If
    Call CleanClipBoard
    Exit Function
errHandler:
    SaveEmbeddedOleObjectToDisk.ERROR = Err.Description
    Call CleanClipBoard
End Function


Private Function GetPastedFile( _
    ByVal Folder As String _
    ) _
    As String

    Dim sCurFile As String
    Dim sNewestFile As String
    Dim dCurDate As Date
    Dim dNewestDate As Date

    Folder = Folder & "\"
    sCurFile = Dir$(Folder & "*.*", vbNormal)
    Do While Len(sCurFile) > 0
        dCurDate = FileDateTime(Folder & sCurFile)
        If dCurDate > dNewestDate Then
            dNewestDate = dCurDate
            sNewestFile = Folder & sCurFile
        End If
        sCurFile = Dir$()
    Loop
    GetPastedFile = sNewestFile
End Function


Private Sub CleanClipBoard()
    OpenClipboard 0
    EmptyClipboard
    CloseClipboard
End Sub
```

Comment: Please help me out

Comment: pl pl help me out , i really need to end this mini project i am working on,

Comment: pl help me out..